# Quote all the value of an array as text

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following array:

```
arr1=("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f")
```

and I want to display the array as quote. So my expected output from echo would be this:

```
AA_ENABLE_HOOKS=("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f")
```

I have done the following code it almost display what I want but I don't like it:

```
#!/bin/bash

arr1=("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f")

var_quote=$( printf "\"%s\" " "${arr1[@]}")

echo "AA_ENABLE_HOOKS=(${var_quote})"
```

The output is

```
AA_ENABLE_HOOKS=("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" ) // notice I have space at the end
```

Is there alternative for my above code in bash?

My current workaround for one-liner command is:

```
echo "AA_ENABLE_HOOKS=($( printf "\"%s\" " "${arr1[@]}" | sed -e 's/\ *$//g'))"
```

Comment: A loop, through the elements.

Comment: Is there another way without loop, the original array have more than 100 ^_^ .. Thinking it would affect performance.

Comment: `echo "AA_ENABLE_HOOKS=("${var_quote% }")"`

Comment: `var_quote=${var_quote% }` would remove the trailing blank from the variable `var_quote`.

Comment: Is this perhaps an [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)? I would be interested, **why** you want to do this, and whether it wouldn't be an option to put the quotes already into the array itself.

Comment: BTW, wrt performance, a loop is only a problem if you create a child process for each array element. As long as you avoid this, even a large array should be processed fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
$ echo "AA_ENABLE_HOOKS=(${arr1[@]@Q})"
AA_ENABLE_HOOKS=('a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f')
```

See **${parameter@operator}** in [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). This was introduced in bash 4.4

Or, if this is intended as a serialization technique:

```bash
$ declaration=$(declare -p arr1)
$ echo "${declaration/arr1/AA_ENABLE_HOOKS}"
declare -a AA_ENABLE_HOOKS=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c" [3]="d" [4]="e" [5]="f")
```

Comment: A little bit confused, does the Q stands for quote ? Trying to read it to make it become double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: single or double, does it really matter?

Comment: yes it does matter.  the value can have spaces. isn't `"a a a a"` better than 'a a a a'?

Comment: Those are exactly the same string.

Comment: Thank you. My thought was, it was better to have double quotes for element with spaces. I forgot what was the case. But for now I'll use this method. Thanks a lot.